# Submit form-action from submit button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function

I have a from with 3 submit buttons. 

Each submit button has it's own `formaction`.

My question, how can I submit a specific submit button with the associated form-action in a JavaScript function?

Answer (score 0):

Each submit button has a name associated with it. This name goes to the server with value attribute when you hit it. Only the name=value will go to the server when you hit it.

```
function execute(value){
  if(value == '1'){
  doSomthing()
}else if(value == '2') {

dosomethingelse();

}
document.form.submit(); // or jquery version of the same. 

}
```

on button's onclick = "execute(1);" and on next button's onclick = "execute(2);
take input type ="button" not submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
document.getElementById('yoursubmitbuttonsid').submit();
```

Comment: You should put apostrophes around the id, but you should also lose the hash-sign, that's for jQuery.

Comment: @Andy G, true, perhaps i should just put PLACEHOLDER in future

Comment: I'm getting a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`